# Qual a diferença em ter um JKS ou um PKCS12 assinando meu app Android?

Tags: android, keystore

Estava gerando uma *keystore* para minha aplicação pelo Android Studio e recebi o seguinte aviso:

> Key was created with errors:
>
> Warning:
>
> O armazenamento de chaves **JKS** usa um formato proprietário. É
>   recomendada a migração para **PKCS12**, que é um formato de padrão
>   industrial que usa "`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\test.jks -destkeystore C:\test.jks -deststoretype pkcs12`".

Resolvi pesquisar, encontrei uma comparação no [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3932615/8839059). Até onde entendi, **JKS** é o padrão do Java. Isso me deixou confuso se eu deveria ou não gerar um **PKCS12**, já que minha aplicação é em **Kotlin** e na compilação é convertida para **Java**, conforme [documentação oficial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/compiling-and-running.html).

Qual a diferença em ter um **JKS** ou um **PKCS12** assinando meu aplicativo?

Faz sentido se preocupar com isso no desenvolvimento de um app pequeno?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### JKS

O **JKS** é um arquivo de segurança criptografado usado para armazenar um conjunto de chaves ou certificados criptográficos no formato binário e requer uma senha para que o arquivo seja aberto.

Nesse caso específico, O JKS está sendo utilizado para identificar o autor (pessoa/empresa) do aplicativo Android durante o processo de *build* e posteriormente também na publicação no Google Play ou na instalação do `.apk` (quando o SO exibe uma mensagem dizendo que o aplicativo é de uma fonte desconhecida, por exemplo).

### PKCS#12

Como dito [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3932615/8839059) o JKS não é facilmente acessível de fora do Java, mas isso não é um problema para o caso em específico da pergunta (usando Kotlin/Java). Os arquivos **PKCS#12**, são uma maneira neutra em relação à linguagem para armazenar chaves privadas e certificados criptografados, e existe há tempo suficiente para que seja suportado em quase todos os lugares.

Uma nota importante é que, conforme visto no [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) e na publicação do [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/229), o PKCS#12 se tornou o formato padrão de *keystore* para o **Java 9**. As motivações para isso estão em tradução livre abaixo:

> As *keystores* JKS podem armazenar apenas chaves privadas e
> certificados de chave pública confiáveis e são baseadas em um formato
> proprietário que não é facilmente extensível a novos algoritmos
> criptográficos.
>
> O PKCS#12 é um formato extensível, padrão e amplamente suportado para
> armazenar chaves criptográficas. A partir do JDK 8, as *keystores*
> PKCS#12 podem armazenar chaves privadas, certificados de chave pública
> confiáveis e chaves secretas. A mudança para PKCS#12 melhora a
> integridade e a confidencialidade da keystore. Também abre
> oportunidades de interoperabilidade com outros sistemas que também
> suportam o PKCS#12.

Então, apesar de ambos funcionarem e isso ser apenas um *warning* do Android Studio, faz sentido passar a usar PKCS#12 pelas vantagens e apoio que está recebendo.

### Convertendo o JKS para PKCS#12

Parar migrar o formato da Keystore, você pode fazer uso do comando `keytool -importkeystore`. Seria algo como:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\test.jks -srcstoretype JKS -destkeystore C:\test.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

O `keytool -importkeystore` possui uma lista de parâmetros [definidos na documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_importkeystore) que você pode utilizar, por exemplo, caso seu keystore tenha uma senha.

| Parâmetro | Definição |
| --- | --- |
| `-srckeystore keystore` | Nome do keystore de origem |
| `-destkeystore keystore` | Nome do keystore de destino |
| `-srcstoretype type` | Tipo do keystore de origem |
| `-deststoretype type` | Tipo do keystore de destino |
| `-srcstorepass arg` | Senha do keystore de origem |
| `-deststorepass arg` | Senha do keystore de destino |
| `-srcprotected` | Keystore de origem protegido por senha |
| `-srcprovidername name` | Nome do provedor do keystore de origem |
| `-destprotected` | Keystore de destino protegido por senha |
| `-destprovidername name` | Nome do provedor do keystore de destino |
| `-srcalias alias` | *Alias* de origem |
| `-destalias alias` | *Alias* de destino |
| `-srckeypass arg` | Senha da chave de origem |
| `-destkeypass arg` | Senha da chave de destino |
| `-noprompt` | Não perguntar |
| `-providerclass class [-providerarg arg]` | Adicionar provedor de segurança por nome de classe totalmente qualificado com um argumento opcional de configuração |
| `-providerpath list` | Classpath do provedor |
| `-v` | Saída detalhada (verbosa) |

[Neste artigo](https://dzone.com/articles/extracting-a-private-key-from-java-keystore-jks) também há algumas informações sobre a conversão.